# Using reflection and a List<>, can one return an array of specific properties via an extension method?

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, collections, extension-methods

I'm not certain of the terminology so forgive my lack of clarity: Given a List<someclass> collection, can one create an extension method utilizing refection that allows one to return an array of specific class members/properties in the list collection by using the properties name? I realize the internal types may vary but the extension method would return the correct type.

```
public class someClass
{
    public someClass(UInt32 _someInt, Double _someDouble, String _someString)
    {
        someInt = _someInt;
        someDouble = _someDouble;
        someString = _someString;
    }
    public UInt32 someInt { get; set; }
    public Double someDouble { get; set; }
    public String someString { get; set; }

  }

...
List<someClass> listOfClasses = new List<someClass>();
listOfClasses.Add(new someClass(...));
listOfClasses.Add(new someClass(...));
listOfClasses.Add(new someClass(...));

//an extension function that does something like this
object[] propDouble = listOfClasses.ToArray("someDouble");
```

Comment: Nothing. Just looking at answers now...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var propDouble = listOfClasses.Select(x => typeof(someClass)
                                           .GetProperty("someDouble")
                                           .GetValue(x)).ToArray();
```

Comment: This throws an error:No overload method 'getvalue' takes one argument.

Comment: @Gio: Which .NET framework are you using, if you use .NET 4.5, it's fine, if you are below, try `GetValue(x, null)`

Comment: That was it. Not exactly an extension method but good enough.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: Yes

How:

```
object[] propDouble = listOfClasses.Select(o => o.GetType()
                                                 .GetField("someDouble")
                                                 .GetValue(o)).ToArray();
```

You can convert this to an Extension Method easily.

Answer (score 0):

Does this not satisfy what you want???

```
List<someclass> L;
IEnumerable<DesiredPropertyType> Properties = 
     L.Select(Item => Item.DesiredProperty).ToArray();
```

Comment: I think he wants to specify the property name at runtime.